# Stuck in infinite loop

Tags: c#, foreach, try-catch, infinite-loop, do-while

I cant see the problem here.

I am stuck in an infinite loop when I call an entry.

I am doing wcf so I have my server working fine. This is my client. Everything works if i take the loops out. But I need these for the menu. So I know my code is right but my loops aren't.

Can't see where I'm going wrong.

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            BikeReference.BikeSalesClient bikeRef = new BikeClient.BikeReference.BikeSalesClient();
            String menu = "\n\nEnter:\n" +
                "0 to get all the bike stock;\n" +
                "1 to get all the bike types;\n" +
                // ...
                "8 to quit:\n";

            Console.WriteLine(menu);

            // will throw FormatException if not int
            int entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            do
            {
                switch (entry)
                {
                    case 0:
                        foreach (var obj in bikeRef.GetAllBikeStock())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("");
                            Console.WriteLine("Bike ID: {0}", obj.IdBikeStock);
                            Console.WriteLine("Bike Type ID: {0}", obj.IdBikeType);
                            // ...
                            Console.WriteLine("Sold: {0}", obj.isItSold);
                            //break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine(bikeRef.UpdateBikeStock(15));
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unrecognised option...");
                        break;
                }
            }
            while (entry != 7);
        }

        catch (Exception)//(Exception e)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change your entry variable inside the loop

```
int entry = 0; //Init
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(menu);

    // will throw FormatException if not int
    entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    ...
} while (entry != 7);
```

Comment: Error 1 The name 'entry' does not exist in the current context at this line: while (entry != 7);

Comment: initialie entry outside the loop (I added into answer)

Comment: Sorry I dont know what you mean?

Comment: see the code in the answer: I added the int entry = 0; line before going into the loop. Entry would not exist outside of the curly braces if not declared outside so the variable would not be accessible in the while(entry != 7) test at the end.

Comment: Error 1 A local variable named 'entry' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'entry', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope to denote something else is the error I get when I add that line

Comment: It would help if i read the code changes properly. being dyslexic doesnt help. Your answer was right all along thank u :) oh apart from it was int entry; not int entry = 0;

Answer (score 4):

Inside the loop you are not modifiying the variable "entry". So unless your first entry = 7 you will be stuck in your loop, because `(entry != 7)` it always be true on the `while (entry != 7);`

Add the line `entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` before `switch (entry)` This way you will keep asking for "entry" given the possibly to entry be equal to 7. Thus, getting out of the loop.

```
    int entry;

    do
    {  
        Console.WriteLine(menu);

        entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        switch (entry)
        //...
   }while (entry != 7);
```

Answer (score 2):

As written above you have to change the `entry` variable inside the loop:

```
class Client
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            BikeReference.BikeSalesClient bikeRef = new BikeClient.BikeReference.BikeSalesClient();
            String menu = "\n\nEnter:\n" +
                "0 to get all the bike stock;\n" +
                "1 to get all the bike types;\n" +
                // ...
                "8 to quit:\n";

            Console.WriteLine(menu);

                // will throw FormatException if not int
                int entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            do
            {
                switch (entry)
                {
                    case 0:
                        foreach (var obj in bikeRef.GetAllBikeStock())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("");
                            Console.WriteLine("Bike ID: {0}", obj.IdBikeStock);
                            Console.WriteLine("Bike Type ID: {0}", obj.IdBikeType);
                            // ...
                            Console.WriteLine("Sold: {0}", obj.isItSold);
                            //break;
                        }
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Console.WriteLine(bikeRef.UpdateBikeStock(15));
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Unrecognised option...");
                        break;
                }
            entry = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            while (entry != 7);
        }

        catch (Exception)//(Exception e)
        {
           // Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for an input after the switch. otherwise the entry can't become != 7